# NetBackup's bplist doesn't get user/group info for Windows files

Tags: netbackup

I'm trying to get information about storage consumption from NetBackup's
bplist output. I'm running NBU 6.0MP5 on a RHEL 3 server.

The server is backing up several Solaris, Linux, and Windows machines.

When I use bplist to get information about files backed up on any UNIX
machine I get something like this:

```
# bplist -C unixclient -R 99 -l -s 01/28/2006 -e 01/29/2006 /
drwxr-xr-x test ccase 0 Nov 16 09:28 /l/home2/test/
-rw------- test ccase 4737 Jan 06 17:54 /l/home2/test/.bash_history
-rw-rw-r-- test ccase 104 Nov 11 2004 /l/home2/test/.bashrc
```

However, when I use it to list files backed up on any Windows client I
can't get the user and group information. They both always appear as
'root'. Like this:

```
# bplist -C winclient -t 13 -R 99 -l -s 02/20/2006 /
drwx------ root root 0 Feb 20 14:26 /C/temp/
-rwx------ root root 41 Feb 20 14:26 /C/temp/asdf.txt
drwx------ root root 0 May 25 2004 /C/temp/CTRMNGR/
```

Does anyone know why bplist doesn't show the correct user/group for
Windows files?

If it can't, is there a way to get that information using another
command?

Thanks.

Gustavo.

Comment: If you haven't already, you might want to ask on the symantec connect forums, Stumpr probably knows the answer :-)

Comment: +1 Stumpr's posted knowledge got me through my first nbu implementation 6 yrs ago.

Comment: It looks like this is a limitation of the bplist tool when running against a windows backup, from a *nix system.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the `-nt_files` option?

Comment: This isn't it, tested :-(

Comment: Nope. This options just changes the way file names are presented in the output, with backward slashes instead of forward ones.